# How to show progress bar while uploading multiple images to Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I made function that upload multiple images to storage and save links to document but i can't figure out how to monitor progress.

```
const getURLS = async () => {
    const promises = [];
    images &&
        images.map((image) => {
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image?.file?.name + v4()}`);
            promises.push(
                uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, dataURLtoBlob(image.data_url)).then((uploadResult) => {
                    return getDownloadURL(uploadResult.ref);
                })
            );
        });

    const urls = await Promise.all(promises);

    try {
        await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
            message: data,
            createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
            createdBy: user,
            likes: [],
            comments: [],
            images: urls,
        }).then(() => {
            setData('');
            setImages([]);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

How to add [firebase monitor upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en&authuser=0#monitor_upload_progress) to this function?
I tried different ways but it dosn't work

thx for help

Answer (score 1):

The [`uploadBytesResumable()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#uploadbytesresumable) does not return a promise but an `UploadTask`. You can iterate over all the images selected and track their progress individually as shown below:

```
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([])
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState([])

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const files = e.target.files
    const newImages = []
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      newImages.push(files[i])
    }
    setImages(newImages)
  }

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      const image = images[i]
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${image.name}`)
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, image)
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100

        setProgress((prevProgress) => {
          const newProgress = [...prevProgress]
          newProgress[i] = progress.toFixed(2)
          return newProgress
        })
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }, async () => {
        const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
        // Add to Firestore
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      {progress.map((progress, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{images[i].name}  {progress}%</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Each file is uploaded separately so you would have to implement some logic to get all URLs together and add in Firestore document like you can call a function when progress of all uploads i.e. all items in *progress* array become 100.